# Using UIAlertController Action To Programatically Link To Embedded UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

The user is currently on a ViewController that was presented `Modally`.

I am trying to hook up a UIAlertViewController's `OK` Button Action to programatically link to a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Like so:

[image]
This is a snippet of my relevant code:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

....// some code

case .Restored:

....// some code
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You!", message: "You now have FULL ad-free Access", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
// Goto Main Page:
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMainViewController");
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
alert.addAction(OKAction)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

break;

default:
break;
}
```

Essentially, when the user restores a purchase (or makes a successful), I would like them to click `OK` to send them to another ViewController - `MainMainViewcontroller`.

But when I click the `OK` button, nothing happens.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance kind Sirs/Mesdames ;)

Comment: Does your modally presented view controller is embedded in a navigation controller? If not, the "navigationController" property resolves to nil and nothing happen beyond this point. Try to edit your presentation line to self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Since your MainMainViewController is inside a UINavigationController, so create an instant of UINavigationController and present that one.

Comment: @Amit89 Perfectamundo! Yes, I was trying to programatically link to the embedded ViewController, when I should have been linking to the NavigationController 'holding' the ViewController. May this weekend shower you with goodness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this way.

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

....// some code

case .Restored:

....// some code
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You!", message: "You now have FULL ad-free Access", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
// Goto Main Page:
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Navigation");
self.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
alert.addAction(OKAction)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

break;

default:
break;
}
```